# i cannot disable or hide CRUD Operations column in DxDataGrid DevExtreme

Tags: angular, devexpress, devextreme

I use the DxDataGrid DevExtreme and Angular components.
I wanted to completely delete the main operation buttons (CRUD Operations) of the table by clicking on a button.
I have defined a variable for this but when the button is clicked it changes its value but does no operations !!

How can I disable or hide CRUD Operations column in DxDataGrid DevExtreme?

[CRUD Operations image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YvPI2.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you can access the column of edit and delete then you can hide using 
*ngIf="false" .   Or you can directly remove that column from the code

Comment: Yes, that is quite right. That was the last method I used.
But I've tried about ten methods, my problem was that it only recognizes the variable I defined, and when we click on a button it no longer changes the variable and doesn't recognize the grid.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same challenge. I resolved it by setting the mode="cell", this also gives me control at granular level.

```
mode="cell"
```